# Does Spring @Autowired create a new instance for every new API request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to know if Spring `@Autowired` creates a new instance every time for a new API request. I am using `@Autowired`for my service class.

Comment: no, the bean's default scope is Singleton. You can learn about all the different scopes for a bean here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Answer (score 8):

No it doesn't unless you have specifically created your bean to Request scope.

When you create a bean by annotating the service class with `@Service`, `@Component` etc. or by creating a method which instantiates your service class and is annotated with `@Bean` the default scope is singleton. So only one instance will be created and injected to all the places where `@Autowired` is used.

If you need request scope you need to annotate the service class or bean creation method with `@RequestScope` or `@Scope("request")`. This is only supported inside of a Web app context.

Comment: Official documentation on bean scopes: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes